# Issue with splitting Excel file (.xlxs) with Powershell based on column values

Tags: powershell

I have the below script that was posted here: [Split Excelfile .xlxs with Powershell based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060404/split-excelfile-xlxs-with-powershell-based-on-column-values/69578587#69578587) and it works as described but I am experiencing an issue.

The script will check one xlsx file and sort the content by unique values in column A and then copy these data set and create a new file.

The issue I am having is out of about 4000 files, 20 of them are created with the full data set from the original file. The rest of the files a split and created correctly. Not sure as to why this is occurring. Any help is appreciated.

```
Function Create-Excel-Spreadsheet {
Param($NameOfSpreadsheet)

# open excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true

# add a worksheet
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$xl_wksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$xl_wksht.Name = $NameOfSpreadsheet

return $workbook
}


$objexcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $objexcel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx") # Changing path for test.xlsx file.

$objexcel.Visible = $true
$objexcel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)

$usedRange = $ws.UsedRange
$usedRange.AutoFilter()

$totalRows = $usedRange.Rows.Count


$rangeForUnique = $usedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize($UsedRange.Rows.Count-1) 
[string[]]$UniqueListOfRowValues = $rangeForUnique.Columns.Item(1).Value2 | sort -Unique

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $UniqueListOfRowValues.Count; $i++) {
    $newRange = $usedRange.AutoFilter(1, $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i])

    $workbook = Create-Excel-Spreadsheet $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i]
    $wksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

    $range = $ws.UsedRange.Cells
    $range.Copy()

    $wksheet.Paste($wksheet.Range("A1"))
    $workbook.SaveAs("C:\temp\" + $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i], $xlFixedFormat)
    $workbook.Close()
}
```

Comment: If you do not give at least a file that is not splited, it will be hard to guess the problem.

Comment: There is only 1 file that was not split (the original file). This has over 700,000 lines containing data relating to unique values. Each unique value can have multiple lines which is why I wanted them split into separate files.

The files that are split are for the most part, fine, except for the 20 odd that contain all the data from the original file but its showing as split based on the unique value.

Comment: Example of the data the original file has that needs to be split. It shows amounts and dates per unique ID:
124p50406 -66.6 2021-04-28
124p50406 846.7 2021-06-14
135p1 0 2017-10-18
135p1 0 2017-10-18
135p1 0 2020-08-28
135p1003 -0.5 2015-07-02
135p1003 -40.7 2015-07-02
135p1003 -40.7 2015-07-16
135p1003 40.7 2015-07-16
Unique ID 135p1003 for example, has 4 lines and this needs to be taken from the original file and split into a separate file. The file is then named as the unique ID.
it works but eventually a file contains data for other multiple unique IDs as well.

Comment: Something strange in those particular values that the autofilter does not like?  `Range.AutoFilter()` will return true/false so you can check that and if false is returned do a `Write-Error` so you can see what values are erring if any.  `if (-not $usedRange.AutoFilter(1, $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i])) { Write-Error $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i] }`

Comment: The values all begin with 135pXXXX so its odd it works 95% of the file. When running the script it always returned true with 'Range.AutoFilter()' set - even when the issue occurs but the file saves correctly and is named correctly. I will add in the 'Write-Error' to see if anything is returned.

Comment: And now I am randomly receiving an error. It creates a file for a specific person but its empty. but files after this error create correctly and does not happen every file. Error below:

Unable to get the Paste property of the Worksheet class
At line:44 char:5
+     $wksheet.Paste($wksheet.Range("A1"))
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: You keep creating new Excel instances and ditto workbooks plus worksheets  (all COM objects), but nowhere do you ever quit excel and release all those objects from memory.. This is asking for problems.

Comment: Thanks Theo. Can you advise where and how I would do this in my script. I am not too familiar with this as I am just starting out with powershell an excel automation.